# For open-source licenses with an acknowledgement clause, how obvious does the notice need to be?

Tags: licensing

In licenses such as that of [libjpeg](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/third_party/libjpeg/README?revision=369) and [freetype](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/docs/FTL.TXT), there are clauses like the following:

> (2) If only executable code is distributed, then the accompanying
>   documentation must state that "this software is based in part on the work of
>   the Independent JPEG Group".

or:

> o Redistribution in binary form must provide a  disclaimer  that
>    states  that  the software is based in part of the work of the
>    FreeType Team,  in  the  distribution  documentation.

Is putting a notice in a text file in the installation directory enough? Or is a more obvious notice typically needed? For a non-open-source end application, what's the usual way to display these mandatory acknowledgments?

Comment: if their license is *copyleft*, as opposed to merely open-source, then any application that uses them would need to also be open source. suggest you edit the title.

Comment: @TZHX, ah, indeed. Although the LGPL is copyleft and allows closed-source apps to use LGPL libraries, under certain conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the applications that I've seen include a note in their Help > About box, EULA, or web site that says, basically, "For information on third party licenses, see *url or document*."  For example:

- OpenOffice.org includes the following clause in its EULA: "Third Party Code. Additional copyright notices and license terms applicable to portions of the Software are set forth in the THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.html file." Within the third party license readme file, each library gets its own section with wording similar to the following:

  > The following software may be included in this product:William's Wonderful Widgets; Use of any of this software is governed by the terms of the license below:

  Copies of the LGPL and GPL are included at the end.
- Google Chrome includes a notice in its Help > About screen: "Google Chrome is made possible by the Chromium open source project and other open source software." "Open source software" here is a link bringing up a credits page that lists each component, its homepage, and its license.
- VMware devotes [a section of their web site](http://www.vmware.com/download/open_source.html) to collecting all of their open source licenses and source code and includes a link to this site in their EULA. Installation directories also include license lists similar to OpenOffice.org's.